# Material Angular Table row cell render(calculate) conditonally when checkbox is checked in Angular 13

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

[image: checkbox]

How can I achieve that the result calculated(not rendered) only when the checkbox in the row checked in angular-material-table.(See on pic)Otherwise it has to be blank. Its just a simple multiplier operation. I have no idea how can I get a connection in each row to the checkbox checked property.

My html:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
  <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Ex. Mia" #input>
</mat-form-field>

<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="cb">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> CheckBox </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> <mat-checkbox  ></mat-checkbox> </td>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="a">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> A </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.a}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="b">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> B </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.b}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="result">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Result </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.a * row.b}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>


    <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
      <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter "{{input.value}}"</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" aria-label="Select page of users"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Components.ts:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

export interface InputData {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  a: number;
  b: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['cb', 'name', 'a', 'b', 'result'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<InputData>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  public myForm: FormGroup;
  public labels = [27, 20, 5];
  public actualVat: number = 27;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    const vmi = [{id: 1, name: 'first', a: 20, b: 1.1}, {id: 1, name: 'second', a: 35, b: 1.7},];

    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(vmi);
  }

  onFormSubmit() {
    if (this.myForm.valid) {
      this.actualVat = this.myForm.value.category;
      console.log(this.actualVat);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      category: [27, Validators.required],

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you could bind a models property to the checkbox with [(ngModel)]="row.exampleBoolProperty". Or you could use the "change" event emitter from the checkbox: (change)="setValue(row, $event.checked)". Then you could set the value in your component. e.g. setValue(row, event) {row.isChecked = event}. You need definetly to add a new property to your data source.

Answer (score 1):

you need add a property to every object example [checked] and with this controlling row is selected or not

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic table
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns = ['checked', 'position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}

export interface Element {
  checked: boolean;
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  highlighted?: boolean;
  hovered?: boolean;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  { checked: false, position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { checked: false, position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { checked: false, position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { checked: false, position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  { checked: false, position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
  { checked: false, position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
  { checked: false, position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
  { checked: false, position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
  { checked: false, position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
  { checked: false, position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
  { checked: false, position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na' },
  { checked: false, position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg' },
  { checked: false, position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al' },
  { checked: false, position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si' },
  { checked: false, position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P' },
  { checked: false, position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S' },
  { checked: false, position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl' },
  { checked: false, position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar' },
  { checked: false, position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K' },
  { checked: false, position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca' },
];


/**  Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

```css
.example-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 500px;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.mat-table {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="checked">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Check</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
        <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="element.checked"></mat-checkbox>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <ng-container *ngIf="element.checked">
         {{element.weight}} 
        </ng-container>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="{hovered: row.hovered, highlighted: row.highlighted}" (mouseover)="row.hovered = true" (mouseout)="row.hovered = false"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>


<!-- Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
```